# Import and ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, modulenotfounderror

If have a problem with Import or ModuleNotFoundError.

For example is here an folder structure:

```
test/
│   
├───demoA
│       test1.py
│       __init__.py
│       
└───demoB
        test2.py
        __init__.py
```

This is the content of test1.py

```
def hello():
  print("hello")
```

This is the content of test2.py

```py
test1.hello()
```

This issue also occurs when I've set up a Python environment. I'm using VS Code as my editor, and I have Python 3.11.4 installed. I've also tried it from a different drive, exactly the same. Import and ModuleNotFound errors are really frustrating.
I've already tried several things I found online. I'm also using Windows 10.

Example 1: When i tried this:

```py
from demoA import test1
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demoA import test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 2: When i tried this:

```py
from demoA import test1
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demoA import test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 3: When i tried this:

```py
from demoA import test1 as t1
t1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demoA import test1 as t1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 4: When i tried this:

```py
import demoA.test1 as t1
t1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import demoA.test1 as t1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 5: When i tried this:

```py
from demoA.test1 import hello

hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demoA.test1 import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 6: When i tried this:

```py
import demoA.test1 as demoA_test1

demoA_test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import demoA.test1 as demoA_test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 7: When i tried this:

```py
import demoA
demoA.test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import demoA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA
```

Example 8: When i tried this:

```py
from . import test1

test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import test1
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Example 9: When i tried this:

```py
from ..demoA import test1

test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..demoA import test1
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Example 10: When i tried this:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_demoA')
from demoA import test1
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from demoA import test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 11: When i tried this:

```py
import importlib
test1 = importlib.import_module('demoA.test1')
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    test1 = importlib.import_module('demoA.test1')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 12: When i tried this:

```py
from demoA import test1
from demoB import test2
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demoA import test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 13: When i tried this:

```py
module_name = 'demoA.test1'
module = __import__(module_name, fromlist=['hello'])
module.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 2, in <module>
    module = __import__(module_name, fromlist=['hello'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 14: When i tried this:

```py
module_code = open('path_to_demoA/test1.py').read()
module_globals = {}
exec(module_code, module_globals)
module_globals['hello']()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    module_code = open('path_to_demoA/test1.py').read()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path_to_demoA/test1.py'
```

Example 15: When i tried this:

```py
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = 'path_to_test'
from demoA import test1
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from demoA import test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 16: When i tried this:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('full_path_to_test/demoA')
from test1 import hello
hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test1 import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test1'
```

Example 17: When i tried this:

```py
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("test1", "path_to_demoA/test1.py")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
module.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test1 import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test1'
```

Example 18: When i tried this:

```py
import sys
import os

test_path = os.path.abspath('path_to_test')
sys.path.append(test_path)

from demoA import test1
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    from demoA import test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 19: When i tried this:

```py
import os
import sys

test_path = os.path.abspath('path_to_test')
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = test_path

from demoA import test1
test1.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 7, in <module>
    from demoA import test1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

Example 20: When i tried this:

```py
import sys
import os
import importlib

module_name = 'demoA.test1'
module_path = os.path.join('path_to_test', module_name.replace('.', os.path.sep) + '.py')

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

module.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 8, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

Example 21: When i tried this:

```py
import os

module_name = 'demoA.test1'
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('path_to_test', *module_name.split('.'))) + '.py'
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

module.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
           ^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'importlib' is not defined
```

Example 22: When i tried this:

```py
import os
import importlib.util

os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = 'path_to_test'
module_name = 'demoA.test1'
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_name.replace('.', os.path.sep) + '.py')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

module.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 936, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1073, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1130, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Yeffarson\\Documents\\code\\import_module_test\\demoA\\test1.py'
```

Example 23: When i tried this:

```py
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join('..', 'demoA'))

from test1 import hello
hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Yeffarson\Documents\code\import_module_test\test\demoB\test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from test1 import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test1'
```

Example 24: When i tried this:

```py
import os
import importlib.util

base_directory = 'path_to_test'
module_name = 'demoA.test1'
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(base_directory, *module_name.split('.'))) + '.py'

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

module.hello()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 936, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1073, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1130, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Yeffarson\\Documents\\code\\import_module_test\\path_to_test\\demoA\\test1.py'
```

Comment: All of these depend on how you're starting your examples in the first place.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on `setup.py` as this makes your life a lot easier if you're managing a long-term project with many directories. [This resource](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) may help. If it is a small project with only a few files then this may not be worth it, but it's still good practice.

Comment: @jahank thanks for suggesting this I am getting to know about this for the very first time too and yes this is far better a solution and handling of the issue.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Python is unaware of a sibling package. Therefore, `demoB` needs to be imported as a module. You can do this by using: `$ python3 -m demoB.test2`?

When I enter this in the console, I receive an error message again:

Comment: @jahank `setup.py` is deprecated, so reading up on it is a bad idea. The article you've linked is 15 years old and describes Python 2.x.

Comment: @AKX you're right, the document I've linked is old, I didn't realise that. However, the use of `setup.py` is not deprecated. Its use as a command line tool may be, but `setup.py` as a setup file is not, it is still very much usable with Setuptools, albeit in a different way nowadays. [This page](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/) has more information - this is a much more recent resource, I checked this time ;)

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi please see the comment above ^. Setuptools has undergone some significant changes in recent years so please ensure you follow recent documentation/tutorials. The resource I linked is very old, my apologies, so please ignore it.

Comment: @jahank `setup.py` still technically _works_, but no new project should use it; if you want to use setuptools as your PEP 517 build backend, by all means, but [use pyproject.toml for your project metadata](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/#static-vs-dynamic-metadata). (I just talked about this at a meetup last week, concidentally.)

Comment: @AKX valid point, thanks for the suggestion. It has been a while since I used setup.py to be fair, so good to know for when I next need it :)

Answer (score 0):

Given a directory structure:

```
- demoA
  __init__.py
  test1.py
- demoB
  __init__.py
  test2.py
```

with `demoA/test1.py` having

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
```

and `demoB/test2.py` having

```
import sys
print(sys.path[:1])
from demoA.test1 import hello
hello()
```

one can't run `test2.py` directly with `python demoB/test2.py` so it could import from the sibling package:

```
$ python3 demoB/test2.py
['/Users/akx/build/so77827594/demoB']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akx/build/so77827594/demoB/test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demoA.test1 import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoA'
```

This is because when running with that syntax, Python configures `demoB` to be on `sys.path` (as seen above), so Python has no knowledge of the sibling package being there (and in fact, in Python's eyes, there is no `demoB` package either).

Instead, you'll need [to run your module with `-m`, and specify your module as a module path, not as a script file](https://docs.python.org/3.12/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).

```
$ python3 -m demoB.test2
['/Users/akx/build/so77827594']
hello
```

As you can see above, this configures `sys.path` to have the current directory, the one hosting the modules, on it, and everything's fine again.

Comment: I agree with you on this the path should be relative to demo2 and not w.r.t the parent folder